# Unity - Transparency Sort Mode not working properly with Tilemap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, 2d-games

I hope you're all doing great! I'm reaching out to the community today because I've run into a bit of a snag with setting up the Transparency Sort Mode in Unity, and I'm hoping someone here might be able to lend me a hand.

I've been working on a project where I need to manage transparency sorting for different layers, and despite my efforts, I've hit a roadblock. I've set the Transparency Sort Mode to "Custom Axis" and carefully organized all the layers as instructed, but I'm still facing an issue.

To provide a bit more context, the sorting seems to be working smoothly between the "Main" character and the "Chest" object. However, I'm encountering problems when it comes to the "Tilemap" layer. The sorting doesn't seem to function as expected between the "Main" character and the elements within the "Tilemap".

I've reviewed my settings and code multiple times, trying to figure out where I might have gone wrong. I've verified that the sorting layers are correctly configured, and the sorting order values seem appropriate. It's puzzling to me why the sorting works for some objects but not for the "Tilemap".

I've done my due diligence in researching Unity's documentation and various forums, but I haven't been able to find a solution that addresses this specific issue. Since this community seems to be incredibly supportive, I thought it might be a good idea to seek advice or insights here.

If anyone has faced a similar situation or has some experience with transparency sorting intricacies, I would greatly appreciate your input. It's possible that there's a small detail I've overlooked or a configuration step that I've misunderstood. Your assistance could help me move forward with my project and gain a better understanding of Unity's rendering pipeline.

Thank you all so much for taking the time to read this post. I'm looking forward to any suggestions, tips, or solutions you might have to offer.

P.S. Feel free to share any insights here or reach out to me directly if you prefer. Your help means a lot to me!

Here you can find some screenshot:
https://imgur.com/a/3bWehzB

Transparency Sort Mode settings:
[MnpA3cM.png (1920×1080)](https://i.imgur.com/MnpA3cM.png)
Main settings:
[JPQvGpP.png (1920×1080)](https://i.imgur.com/JPQvGpP.png)
Tilemap settings:
[jLGH9RK.png (1920×1080)](https://i.imgur.com/jLGH9RK.png)
Chest settings:
[cqI07J4.png (1920×1080)](https://i.imgur.com/cqI07J4.png)
Tilemap behaviour:
[VAcjCXE.png (1920×1080)](https://i.imgur.com/VAcjCXE.png)
Chest behaviour:
[9MSRMjE.png (1920×1080)](https://i.imgur.com/9MSRMjE.png)

What I Tried:
I've tried changing the rendering mode of the Tilemap to "Individual" to control tile layering. I've also messed with various layer settings for both the main character and the Tilemap. Additionally, I experimented with using a different Tilemap.

Expected Outcome:
My aim was simple:
Main character comes up from the bottom, should be in front of the Tilemap.
Main character comes down from the top, should be behind the Tilemap.

What's Actually Happening:
Surprisingly, the main character always shows up in front of the Tilemap, no matter which direction it's moving in.
I've been diving into my setup and configurations, but I can't seem to crack this one. Some details about my current setup:
I've set up the main character and the Tilemap on same sorting layers (does not change if I put them in separate).
Tinkered with the "Order in Layer" values for both to tweak their rendering order.
Made sure the main character and the Tilemap have distinct Z-positions (does not change if they had the same).
I even went into Sorting Groups within a Canvas and tried playing around with camera settings, but the issue persists.